# Change the form of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

If I have a matrix of this form

```
g = matrix(c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1),3,3,byrow=T)
```

How can I turn it into a matrix of this form?

```
g = matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0),3,3,byrow=T)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can reverse the column sequence index and specify it in `j`

```
g1 <- g[, ncol(g):1]
```

Or use `rev`

```
g[, rev(seq_len(ncol(g)))]
```